# How can you make the Wiremock Standalone update recordings when a header already exists but the body is different?

Tags: api

I'm currently using the Wiremock Standalone for recording/playback. However, I'm having the issue where it will record a GET, but if I update the list with a POST and record the GET again it will recognize the existing URL and won't update/record the new GET. Anyone has any idea on how to make it check the body of the file if the URL already exists and update the file with that URL?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone was having the same issue, I found a solution for this. Instead of running the standalone as
 *java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.23.2.jar --https-port XXXX  --record-mappings --proxy-all XXXXXXXX*
I found the wiremock body transformer which completely solved my problem.

Now I am running it this way:
*java -cp "wiremock-body-transformer-1.1.6.jar;wiremock-2.3.1-standalone.jar" com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner --extensions com.opentable.extension.BodyTransformer --https-port XXXX --proxy-all XXXXXXX --record-mappings*

Below is the link where you can find the jar file.

https://github.com/opentable/wiremock-body-transformer